# MySQL order by a column which has multiple numerical values separated by slashes

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table (policy_details) which has column '**notenumber**'  with values:

```
150/1  
150/2  
150/1/2  
150/2/1
```

I need the resultset shown below using query order by **notenumber** asc

```
150/1  
150/1/2  
150/2  
150/2/1
```

I have tried:

```
select *,REPLACE(notenumber, N'/', N'') AS newnotenumber 
from policy_details 
order by newnotenumber asc;
```

I need to fetch **notenumber** in ascending order.

Comment: Could you please elaborate and include the code you have already tried, and more details please? What are you trying to achieve, what is currently occurring when you execute your code etc?

Comment: i have tried 
select *,REPLACE(notenumber, N'/', N'') AS newnotenumber from policy_details order by newnotenumber asc ";

Comment: Is it not giving you expected result??

Comment: yes, but not in order by asc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Far and away the best solution is to redesign your schema to store each part of `notenumber` in a different field.  Barring this, you need to split out each part of `notenumber`, convert it to a numeric type, and order by it.  You'll have to add a clause to the `order by` for each part you split out, there's no way around that.

Example:

```
select
  notenumber,
  replace(substring(substring_index(notenumber, '/', 1), length(substring_index(notenumber, '/', 1 - 1)) + 1), '/', ''),
  replace(substring(substring_index(notenumber, '/', 2), length(substring_index(notenumber, '/', 2 - 1)) + 1), '/', ''),
  replace(substring(substring_index(notenumber, '/', 3), length(substring_index(notenumber, '/', 3 - 1)) + 1), '/', '')
from test
order by
  convert(replace(substring(substring_index(notenumber, '/', 1), length(substring_index(notenumber, '/', 1 - 1)) + 1), '/', ''), signed integer),
  convert(replace(substring(substring_index(notenumber, '/', 2), length(substring_index(notenumber, '/', 2 - 1)) + 1), '/', ''), signed integer),
  convert(replace(substring(substring_index(notenumber, '/', 3), length(substring_index(notenumber, '/', 3 - 1)) + 1), '/', ''), signed integer)
;
```

Note you'll need to insert the index number of the split part **twice** into each `replace` clause.

SQL fiddle for the above solution: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dc935/1/0